# Spinnaker delivery pipeline

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, spinnaker, google-cloud-build

I have some issues about a spinnaker deploy strategy.

I have a microservices app to deploy in Kubernetes and I started to use Spinnaker to manage the deploy workflow.
I use Google Kubernetes Engine and Google Container Registry + Google Cloud Build to manage the image builds. 
The repository is hosted on Github and I have to build a new Docker image once there are some changes on the repository.
In Spinnaker I deploy the application using manifest (v2).

So on one side I have the yaml manifest file used for deploy and on the other side there is the docker image hosted on Google.

I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-kubernetes-engine) to build my delivery pipeline. I run tests and build the image in Google Cloud Build, then Spinnaker detects a new docker image in the registry and it starts to deploy using a manifest stored directly in Spinnaker. This works fine for me.

But what if I would like to version the manifest file and put it into the git repository?
To do so I have to add a Github artifact on Spinnaker, used into the deploy stage as text source.
But it runs only if some changes are found in the manifest file.
So to avoid this I have to set a default file path in the artifact (specifying the git branch to look for). In this way I must work always with the same branch and I can't deploy in a dev environment using different branches with different names. Also, I'd have to set up two Github artifacts, one for dev and one for prod.
I think this is not a good solution.

I would like to know how do you manage a case like this.
Probably I made a mistake in the delivery workflow and I must set manifest statically in Spinnaker. Otherwise I don't know how to get the right copy of the manifest file.

Thank you.

Comment: In spinaker , do you have the concept of environements ? so that you can map the spinaker enviroments on to the github branches , and maybe you can configure spinaker to triger the deployment on change in docker registry and then pull the latest manifest from github branch for that enviroment , i am doing the same workflow , but i am using gitlab and local docker trusted registry with hooks

Comment: Thank you @IjazKhan I found [this tutorial](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/kubernetes-v2-source-to-prod/) and using the option "Using prior execution" on github artifact it seems that my problem is solved. This should work because if no changes were found into manifest file it means that it can use the last one and this is right. In this way I implement a trigger for the docker image and another one for github and they would be executed only if there will be changes on their own side.